# Node.js: How to check the parameters for searching in the file system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, fs

Example of request:

```
node  index.js  --DIR="/Downloads"  --PATTERN=\.js  --TYPE=F  --MIN-SIZE=1G
```

Conditionals for params:

- --TYPE: [D|F] D - directory, F - file
- --PATTERN: regular expression to test file/directory name
- --MIN-SIZE: minimum file size [B|K|M|G]

What methods of **node** **fs** can I use to check up these parameters on match the conditions?

Comment: Regex on [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)'s results + [`fs.stat`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) will be usefull.